# Check if Data value already exists in a json file with liquid

Tags: html, arrays, forms, jekyll, liquid

I created a form to collect user data
Then I used an Api to get the user data
And so far I have been successful ( I displayed the data on my site using jekyll-json-get plugin)

Where the problem is users could be able to register with multiple emails...

The file looks like this
json file

```
{created" => “date”,
“data” => "{
“first name” => “me”,
“email” => “me@me.com”
},
“folder” => “null”
}

{ “created” => “date”,
data" => "{
“first name” => “me2”,
“email” => “me@me.com”
},
“folder” => “null”
}
```

… And so on

What I want to do is..
On form submission if the email entered as been used by anyone else stop form submission and ask for another email.
How do I go about this(am kinda new)

Comment: What server the form is submitting to? Where you are storing this JSON at rest? Jekyll sites only change when you build them, so that means you would need to rebuild every time that data changes. I'm a big fan of Jekyll but it isn't suited to showing user-created data (e.g. comments, user accounts). It's better for owner-created data (e.g. blog posts, articles). There are usually JavaScript solutions for anything that Jekyll isn't suited for that work well with Jekyll (e.g. Disqus for comments, Firebase for serverless user accounts).

Comment: Thank you so much... I thought of this before it's actually more of a request from client, the user collected data(photograph, email and full name) are a fixed number probably less than fifty... And so far I have been successful in doing this.. Although the only problem I have now is that a user can decide to use the same email multiple times and I don't like it..  So I did ---
{% assign emails =  site.data.seeds | map: "data" | map: "email" | inspect %}
 # that lists all the emails in the json file. Now a thinking of way to check on form submission if the email already exists. Any ideas?

Comment: Jekyll converts source files into a static website, it doesn't accept form submissions. Where is your form submitting to?

Comment: The form is submitted to getsimpleform. I load form data using the json API provided and I use the jekyll-get-json plugin to access the data

Comment: You should manage the duplicates there, otherwise you'll just be stopping the form. Users can still submit without the form, or submit the same value multiple times before the duplicate is detected in JavaScript after a Jekyll build.